# Mod rewrite to redirect to 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

Current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule category-([0-9]+)-(.*)-([0-9]+)\.html$ category.php?cid=$1&name=$2&page=$3.php [L]
RewriteRule search-(.*)-([0-9]+)\.html$ search.php?term=$1&page=$2.php [L]
RewriteRule all-covers-([0-9]+)\.html$ all-covers.php?page=$1.php [L]
RewriteRule featured-covers-([0-9]+)\.html$ featured-covers.php?page=$1.php [L]
RewriteRule top-downloaded-([0-9]+)\.html$ top-downloaded.php?page=$1.php [L]
RewriteRule c-([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$ cover.php?id=$1&name=$2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

I want to redirect to 404 from pages like this:
[http://example.com/http://example.com/c-42.html]

Help please

Comment: I don't understand? The URL you want to redirect; is it `example.com/c-42.html` (as per your already existing rewrite rule, or is it as you've posted: `http://example.com/http://example.com/c-42.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is add `^` qualifiers to your regex patterns:

```
RewriteRule ^category-([0-9]+)-(.*)-([0-9]+)\.html$ category.php?cid=$1&name=$2&page=$3.php [L]
RewriteRule ^search-(.*)-([0-9]+)\.html$ search.php?term=$1&page=$2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^all-covers-([0-9]+)\.html$ all-covers.php?page=$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^featured-covers-([0-9]+)\.html$ featured-covers.php?page=$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^top-downloaded-([0-9]+)\.html$ top-downloaded.php?page=$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^c-([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$ cover.php?id=$1&name=$2.php [L]
```

That means, for example, `^c-([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$` will match `http://example.com/c-42.html` but *will no longer match* `http://example.com/http://example.com/c-42.html`. And the latter will automatically end up as a 404.